# Calling JavaScript object property as a constructor from ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I am using a JavaScript library that exposes a constructor as a property of a global object.

In JavaScript, I can call the constructor like this.

```
var thing = new Library.Thing();
```

How do I call the constructor in ClojureScript? None of these work.

```
; These all cause compiler errors
(new (.-Thing js/Library)) ; First arg to new must be a symbol
(new (.Thing js/Library))
(new .-Thing js/Library)
(new .Thing js/Library)
(new js/Library/Thing)     ; Invalid token: js/Library/Thing

; These all compile to different JS than I am looking for
((.-Thing js/Library).) ; Library.Thing.call(null, _SLASH_);
((.Thing js/Library).)  ; Library.Thing().call(null, _SLASH_);
```

It works fine if I use js* but that's cheating, right?

```
(js* "new Library.Thing()")
```

What is the proper way to call a constructor function that is a property of another object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at http://himera.herokuapp.com/synonym.html you can find the specific syntax to instantiate objets in clojurescript.

I wrote this js mock library based in this documentation to make a test:

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
return "Hello, " + this.name;
};


var f={
"hola":"hola juan",

Person:Person

};

var person=new f.Person("Juan");
alert(person.greet());
```

Then from clojurescript you have to use the dot syntax (but prefixing with "js/" your js global type):

```
(let [Person (.-Person js/f)
        juan (Person. "Juan")
        ]
    (.log js/console  (.greet juan)))
```

I don't mention in this answer the :externs property of your cljsbuild compilation beacuse I understand that you are including your js script library directly in your html head document. So, if this line works for you `(js* "new Library.Thing()")` it'll mean that the js library is available  from the cljs-js-compiled.
Anyway, I left an "alert" in the js mock library to check that the file is correctly loaded

I hope it works for you
Juan

Comment: So in other words, if I bind the constructor to a local first, I can call it. `(let [Thing (.-Thing js/Library)] (new Thing))` works fine, as does `(let [Thing (.-Thing js/Library)] (Thing.))`.You are correct about the script being included directly in the document.

Comment: Hi Josh, you are right about the local constructor binding. It's a very curious behavior the dot js constructor ".". Just realizing that you can invoke normal functions with this "." `(defn -log [message]
  (.log js/console message)
)
(-log. "Hello Josh")
`